# C structure initialization?

Tags: c, initialization, structure

How can I initialize a structure if one field in the structure is itself a structure?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use more braces (actually, they're optional, but GCC makes a warning these days).  Here's an example:

```
struct s1 { int a; int b; };
struct s2 { int c; struct s1 s; };

struct s2 my_s2 = { 5, { 6, 3 } };
```

Comment: Optional in only where member `s` is fully initialised (i.e. all members), necessary if you want to only partially initialise the structure.

Comment: In C99 you may use the following notation which is easier to maintain and to read: `struct s2 my_s2 = { .c = 5, .s = { .a = 6, .b = 3 } };`

Answer (score 1):

## Nesting of structure

You can initialize a structure if one field in the structure is itself a structure

```
struct add{
    int house;
    char road;
};
struct emp{
    int phone;
    struct add a;
};

struct emp e = { 123456, 23, "abc"};
printf("%d %d %c",e.phone,e.a.house,e.a.road);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct A
{
int n;
}

struct B
{
A a;
} b;
```

You can initialize n by the following statement. Is this what you are looking for.

```
b.a.n = 10;
```

Comment: In the terms used to define the language, that is an example of *assignment* rather than *initialisation*.  In this context an initialiser is used only at declaration of an object.